# facebook friend selector not appearing/does not load?

Tags: facebook, user-interface, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using the below mentioned code to show a friend-selector list, but it's not loading anymore. It used to work some time back.
It does show that it's loading with the typical facebook style ajax loading animation and after some time nothing happens. Only the button appears, but not the input field in which user can type the friends name. What do I need to do to make the input field appear?

```
<fb:fbml>
  <form action="submit.php" id="testForm" method="post">
  <fb:friend-selector name="uid" idname="ids"></fb:friend-selector>
  <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Add" class="inputbutton" />
  </form>
</fb:fbml>
```

Answer (score 0):

FBML is deprecated.  Try using the current API and see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: Thanks  for the response. I have written my own friends select box. which works ok. BTW! what you meant by "using the current api"? has fb introduced an alternative for above fbml snippet or talking about fetch the friends from graph api and process and show them in select box like i have done now. Thanks

Comment: FBML is dying.  Use the current API means figuring out how to accomplish your tasks with the Graph API.